# Bas64 decode Error

Tags: java, encryption, base64

I have a simple code that encrypt and decrypt string. This encryption and decryption works most of the time except when I try to decrypt this value,

> zxF9LGKNLzPQgkE5/SUbCbCp7SlWFTafGWdfbIylRhwfwMLBLoh/VDYOyg/vK4b+
>   I get this error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 20
```

this encrypted value was generated using below string UUID,

> 32787d1b-abee-49de-af3e-b51f53dd2b96

below is the code that i use to encrypt,

```
try
        {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            final String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(rawString.getBytes(chaEncoding)));
            return new String(encodedString.getBytes(chaEncoding));

        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
```

This is the code i use to decrypt,

```
try
        {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedString.getBytes(chaEncoding)));
            return new String(plainText, chaEncoding);

        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
```

Comment: Character 20 would be a space `' '`. Have you checked  for space? Maybe a `trim` is all you need.

Comment: Is `chaEncoding` something other than ISO-8859-1? You are using `Base64.Encoder.encodeToString()`, which uses that as its charset, but then decoding using a byte array derived using `chaEncoding`. You might want to use `decode(String)` instead of `decode(byte[])` to properly reverse it.

Comment: What is the point of `new String(encodedString.getBytes(chaEncoding))`? You convert a string to bytes using one encoding (`chaEncoding`), then convert the bytes back to a string using another encoding (default). Your only saving grace is that the string is Base-64, i.e. pure ASCII, so as long as encodings are not UTF-16 or UTF-32, that mistaken construct actually does no harm.

Answer (score 0):

Issues is in the "+" sign. I have deployed this as spring boot application so + means "space" in URLs. I changed my code to get encrypted string from request body.
Thanks all.